# How can I wake up device when notifications arrived on Android with react-native-firebase?

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm developing the notification feature using `react-native-firebase` on `React native` in `Android`.

Most of the features(such as remote notification on foreground and background, displaying local notification) are well implemented, but there's one problem I haven't solved.

As I said above, receiving notifications on foreground and background are working well.
When device's screen is off(lock mode or doze mode) the notification is well received with vibrating and sound but screen is not on.
I have tested on Emulator(Nexus 5X with Google play), LG G Flex2, Samsung galaxy S8.

## Expectation

Wake up device (turn on screen) when notifications arrived on Android

## Current Situation

When notifications arrived, sounds and vibrations are working, but screen is off.

I haven't tested on iOS. Here are my configurations.

### gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

### build.gradle (project)

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
}
```

### build.gradle (app)

```
compileSdkVersion 26
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 26
```

### React Native Version

```
"react": "^16.3.0-alpha.1",
"react-native": "0.54.3",
```

### react-native-firebase version

```
"react-native-firebase": "^4.2.0",
```

### client-side receiving notification codes

```
async configureNotifications() {
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
    if (enabled) {
        this.listenNotification();
    } else {
        try {
            await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
            this.listenNotification();
        } catch (e) {
            Alert.alert('', '알림 거부하시면 화재 감지 알림을 받으 실 수 없습니다.');
        }
    }
}

listenNotification() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel(
            'alert',
            'alert',
            firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max,
        ).setDescription('My apps alert');
        firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
    }
    const subProm = [];
    const { account } = this.props;
    const { deviceInfo } = account;

    for (let i = 0; i < deviceInfo.length; i++) {
        subProm.push(firebase.messaging().subscribeToTopic(deviceInfo[i].deviceID));
    }

    Promise.all(subProm).then(() => {
        this.messageListner = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
            let newNotification;

            if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                newNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
                    .setNotificationId(message.messageId)
                    .setTitle(message.data.title)
                    .setBody(message.data.body)
                    .setSound('default')
                    .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High)
                    .android.setChannelId('alert');
            }

            return firebase.notifications().displayNotification(newNotification);
        });
    });
}
```

### client-side background Headless Task handler

```
export default async (message) => {
    console.log('on Background Message');
    console.log(message);
    let newNotification;

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        newNotification = new firebase.notifications.Notification()
            .setNotificationId(message.messageId)
            .setTitle(message.data.title)
            .setBody(message.data.body)
            .setSound('default')
            .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High)
            .android.setChannelId('alert');
    }

    return firebase.notifications().displayNotification(newNotification);
};
```

### index.js

```
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage', () => bgMessaging);
```

### server-side sending notification codes (test version)

#### nodejs with `firebase-admin`

```
var msg = {
    android: {
        ttl: 36000,
        data: {
            title: 'title',
            body: 'body' + topic,
        },
        priority: 'high',
    },
    topic,
};

admin
    .messaging()
    .send(msg)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log('Successfully sent message', res);
        process.exit();
    }, console.error);
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ?

Comment: I too have the same problem, Did you find anything ?

Comment: I can't find any solution.

Comment: Does anyone get to solve this.?

Comment: Anyone ever find the answer to this?